# Node Module to read content of all file types

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, node-modules

I would like to read the content of files in Node.js.
Files like JS, Docs, PDF, JSON, TXT, etc. 
Is there any module that can handle all file types reads.
As from content, I would like to fetch some keywords and do certain operations.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the module fs, https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs.

Comment: But it can't read docs, pdf, excel, ppt, csv contents properly?

Comment: Google you way to different libraries to can do that then.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file

Comment: Like this, I need to install so many individual modules. Like "textract" we can achieve so many files read, is there any alternative for it?